# Interactive Charts in Tcl/Tk

Tags: user-interface, charts, tcl, tk-toolkit

[BLT](http://blt.sourceforge.net/) is the best choice I know. It works, but the style is a little bit outdated. And i suppose it's out of maintenance? Since the lastest [2.4z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blt/files/BLT/BLT%202.4z/) was release in 2002.

[Plotchart](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/plotchart.html) is another great chart library which is part of [tklib](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tklib/) and already builin in tcl 8.5. I tried some examples shipped with [tklib](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tklib/), but it looks like it can only show static charts.

Is there any alternative library available?

Comment: Thank Donal! I'm glad SO has a lot friendly people like you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, there is a forked 2.5 version of BLT here, http://pdqi.com/w/pw/pdqi/Wize/Blt.

You can also try the [Refactored BLT Components](http://wiki.tcl.tk/24533), which are Tcl8.5/8.6 compatible.

Finally, the Tcl wiki page about [BLT](http://wiki.tcl.tk/199), cites a 3.0 version, but I can't find where to grab it.

Comment: Apparently, George Howlett's been working on BLT 3.0 for years. _Nobody else_ has ever seen it as far as I know. You point to exactly the right choices for replacements.